# How to GCDAsyncsocket read xmpp file transfer

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp, gcdasyncsocket

I am using xmpp framework and the TURNSocket class.
Once I have a socks5 connection, GCDasyncsocket I need to receive the data that the other client is sending.

All samples for readdatattodata are working with a terminator like a CrLF how can I read the complete file data that is being send.